# How to remove certain string from last line with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have string that looks something like this

```
<a href="http://www.page.com/01"><img src="http://www.domain.com/test.jpg" alt=""/></a><!--nextpage-->
<a href="http://www.page.com/02"><img src="http://www.domain.com/test.jpg" alt=""/></a><!--nextpage-->
<a href="http://www.page.com/03"><img src="http://www.domain.com/test.jpg" alt=""/></a><!--nextpage-->
```

What I want to do is remove `<a href="http://www.page.com/03">` and `</a><!--nextpage-->` on the last line only! so the final output should look like this:

```
<a href="http://www.page.com/01"><img src="http://www.domain.com/test.jpg" alt=""/></a><!--nextpage-->
<a href="http://www.page.com/02"><img src="http://www.domain.com/test.jpg" alt=""/></a><!--nextpage-->
<img src="http://www.domain.com/test.jpg" alt=""/>
```

This is what I did so far

```js
var str = '<a href="page.com/01"><img src="domain.com/test.jpg" alt=""/></a><!--nextpage-->\n<a href="page.com/02"><img src="domain.com/test.jpg" alt=""/></a><!--nextpage-->\n<a href="page.com/03"><img src="domain.com/test.jpg" alt=""/></a><!--nextpage-->\n';
str = str.slice(0, -20);
alert(str)
```

I managed to remove `</a><!--nextpage-->` on the last line. Now I just don't know how to remove `<a href="page.com/03">` on the last line. Please note the string will always have different amount of lines and urls

Comment: Parse the HTML to DOM and perform DOM manipulation.

Comment: Don't manipulate HTML as a string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to do this using Javascript alone and not DOM Manipulation, here is some code witht he help of regular expression

```
var str = '<a href="page.com/01"><img src="domain.com/test.jpg" alt=""/></a><!--nextpage-->\n<a href="page.com/02"><img src="domain.com/test.jpg" alt=""/></a><!--nextpage-->\n<a href="page.com/03"><img src="domain.com/test.jpg" alt=""/></a><!--nextpage-->\n';
var res = str.split("<!--nextpage-->\n");
var newString = res[res.length-2].replace(/<a href=\"([\w\.\/]*)\">/,"");
newString = newString.replace("</a>","");
alert(newString)
```

Here is a fiddle that achieves the same
https://jsfiddle.net/BoyWithSilverWings/g8bavgtc/

Comment: It doesn't give me the desired result

Comment: I can see that it outputs the last line only. So where did all the other lines disappear to?

Comment: It is saved as an array. You can see the complete output now.

Comment: I noticed the string '<!--nextpage-->' is removed in every line. I only wanted the last line to remove '<!--nextpage-->' . Can you fix that?

Answer (score 2):

Generate a dom element with the content and do the rest.

```js
var str = '<a href="http://www.page.com/01"><img src="http://www.domain.com/test.jpg" alt=""/></a><!--nextpage--><a href="http://www.page.com/02"><img src="http://www.domain.com/test.jpg" alt=""/></a><!--nextpage--><a href="http://www.page.com/03"><img src="http://www.domain.com/test.jpg" alt=""/></a><!--nextpage-->';

// create a div eleemnt
var ele = document.createElement('div');
// set the html content as string
ele.innerHTML = str;
// remove the last child node which is the comment
ele.lastChild.remove();
// get the last child node currently which is the `a` tag
var a = ele.lastChild;
// replace the `a` tag with its children
// this only works if single child is inside the a tag
// otherwise you need to get all children and
// append child using appendChild method
// after appending all just remove the `a` tag
ele.replaceChild(a.firstChild, a);
// get the updated html content
console.log(ele.innerHTML);
```